# A proof that the continuous image of a connected metric space X is an interval in R

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove the above result in the title. However, while trying to prove it I found myself lost without f having the property that it is surjective.

I will provide the outline of my proof using the onto property of f. I just want to know if you can prove this without f being onto.

We use proof by contradiction. Suppose f(X) is not an interval in R. Then by another result we have that f(X) is not connected in R. So there exists non empty disjoint  open subsets G, H of R such that $ f(X) = G \cup H$ . By continuity we have that $ f^{-1}(G) $ and $ f^{-1}(H) $ are open in X.

Now I come to the part where I want to show that X can be written as the union of two non empty disjoint open subsets of X , viz. the above two pre images, but when I want to show that the pre images are non empty I use the fact that since G ,H are nonempty there exists some g in G and h in H so by ontoness there exists some x , y in X such that f(x) = g and f(y) = h. Then that would show that the pre images are nonempty.

I appreciate any feedback thank you.

Comment: You have that $g$ and $h$ are in $f(X)$; so your $x$ and $y$ indeed exist.

Comment: Oh yes I see that now thank you David Mitra